# Using ArcPy to query ArcSDE geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I have three variables: view_name, column_name, and column_content.

column_name contains id, name, address, etc.
column_content contains 123, John, 200 King st, etc.

user specifies the column_name and column_content

a SDE connection file located: c:\gdb.dmz.sde

how to query the database in the view = view_name where column_name = column_content?

using arcpy.da.SearchCursor() function.

Comment: What are you wanting to get out - if the user provides the column name and content - are you just looking for a count of the matching records?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `column_name` is your field name, and `column_content` is the value you are looking for. Using `da.SearchCursor` will certainly get you where you want to be. I am assuming you then wish to find other information from the row once the row is matched. To get this information, the `da.SearchCursor` requires the feature class or table you wish to query and a list of fields you wish to find the values of as its inputs. The cursor returns a tuple of the values in the fields you indicated as your `da.SearchCursor` input. You can use an `if` statement to find the value you are after.

Something like this:

```
fc = r"feature/class/full/path"

column_name = "ADDRESS"
column_content = "123 Way Street"

otherfields = ["ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS"]

fields = [column_name] + otherfields

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, fields)
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] == column_content:
        print "ID:", row[1]
        print "NAME:", row[2]
        print "ADDRESS:", row[3]
del row
del cursor
```